# Docker ps command output is empty when adding a command to the image.run() section

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-docker, selenoid

Environment:

- docker-plugin version: 1.1.2;
- jenkins version: 2.0.50727;
- docker client/server version: 17.12.0-ce;
- Win 10 Pro x64;

**Scenario 1:**
I try to run the Selenoid image via Jenkinsfile with the following command:

```
stage('Start services') {
        docker.image('aerokube/selenoid').
                run('--name selenoid ' +
                        '-p 4444:4444 ' +
                        '-v C:/workspace/selenoid:/etc/selenoid ' +
                        '-v C:/workspace/output:/opt/selenoid/video ' +
                        '-v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ' +
                        '-e "OVERRIDE_VIDEO_OUTPUT_DIR=/C/workspace/output/"')
}
```

**Actual result:**
The container is created and I see the Selenoid container in the docker ps output.

**Scenario 2:**

When I add any command after a point - container doesn't create. Please see the following:

```
stage('Start services') {
        docker.image('aerokube/selenoid').
                run('--name selenoid ' +
                        '-p 4444:4444 ' +
                        '-v C:/workspace/selenoid:/etc/selenoid ' +
                        '-v C:/workspace/output:/opt/selenoid/video ' +
                        '-v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ' +
                        '-e "OVERRIDE_VIDEO_OUTPUT_DIR=/C/workspace/output/"',
                '-video-output-dir /output')
}
```

In this scenario, I added `-video-output-dir /output`. 
BTW I try to add next command after a point: 
`-limit 10`, `-conf /etc/selenoid/browsers.json` -> but still to no avail.

Also, please see the following logs from Jenkins job:

```
[Pipeline] sh
[C:\Jenkins\workspace\pplication_react-app_master-6UL22J3ZHJJMMTIKZO5LDRETFMNMM4TSEGGCZJKAGTM5HBOEAEYQ] Running shell script
+ docker run -d --name selenoid -p 4444:4444 -v C:/workspace/selenoid:/etc/selenoid -v C:/workspace/output:/opt/selenoid/video -v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -e OVERRIDE_VIDEO_OUTPUT_DIR=/C/workspace/output/ aerokube/selenoid -video-output-dir /output
[Pipeline] dockerFingerprintRun
[Pipeline] bat
[pplication_react-app_master-6UL22J3ZHJJMMTIKZO5LDRETFMNMM4TSEGGCZJKAGTM5HBOEAEYQ] Running batch script

C:\Jenkins\workspace\pplication_react-app_master-6UL22J3ZHJJMMTIKZO5LDRETFMNMM4TSEGGCZJKAGTM5HBOEAEYQ>docker ps 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

`Docker ps` command output is empty...

What I'm doing wrong? Maybe I'm so not doing `args` transfer into the run() section?

Comment: You should review the execution logs for the container. Run `docker logs selenoid` on the Jenkins worker and see if it is throwing an error at runtime.

Comment: Also: explicitly naming your container can complicate the next run. You may want to add a `--rm` to the arguments to ensure you're not conflicting on container name.

Comment: @benschumacher, when I add an args after a point I see the following for my selenoid container logs:
`2018/02/13 14:08:09 Loading configuration files...`
`2018/02/13 14:08:09 /usr/bin/selenoid: browsers config: read error: open C:/Program Files/Git/etc/selenoid/browsers.json: no such file or directory`
Could you please tell me, where I should use `--rm` option? right after run? (docker run --rm ...)

Comment: It looks like the selenoid container has bunch of [default arguments](https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid/blob/4cbf6cbc2460185ecc202720dc3e5b964236bd11/Dockerfile#L9) in the `CMD`. When you pass in arguments via the Docker command-line, you're overriding these entirely and thus losing the `-conf /etc/selenoid/browsers.json`, amongst others.

Comment: @benschumacher, I try without args:
`docker.image('aerokube/selenoid').run('--name selenoid -p 4444:4444 
-v C:/workspace/selenoid/:/etc/selenoid:ro 
-v C:/workspace/output/:/opt/selenoid/video/ -v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -e OVERRIDE_VIDEO_OUTPUT_DIR=/C/workspace/output/')`

Comment: Test broken: Please see selenoid logs:
`2018/02/15 23:09:42 [0] [SERVICE_STARTUP_FAILED] [unknown] [start video container: create video container: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: 'C:/workspace/output/:/data:rw']`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Selenoid [Dockerfile](https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid/blob/master/Dockerfile). Important lines are:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/selenoid"]

CMD ["-listen", ":4444", "-conf", "/etc/selenoid/browsers.json", "-video-output-dir", "/opt/selenoid/video/"]
```

That means entrypoint command is always being run and everything inside `CMD` applies only if no args are passed explicitly. In your case you are adding your own arguments:

```
'-video-output-dir /output'
```

That means `CMD` section contents are not applied anymore. But `-conf` is a required argument which defaults to `config/browsers.json`, not `/etc/selenoid/browsers.json`. So correct solution is to add `-conf /etc/selenoid/browsers.json` to your expression.

Comment: It is not working for me... I added  -conf /etc/selenoid/browsers.json after point into run() section and still see empty docker ps output.

Comment: My last command is: `docker.image('aerokube/selenoid').
                        run('--name selenoid ' +
                                '-p 4444:4444 ' +
                                '-v C:/workspace/selenoid/:/etc/selenoid ' +
                                '-v C:/workspace/output/:/opt/selenoid/video ' +
                                '-v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ' +
                                '-e "OVERRIDE_VIDEO_OUTPUT_DIR=C:/workspace/output/"',
                                "-conf /etc/selenoid/browsers.json")`

Comment: This is because you are placing Selenoid arguments in wrong place. In `docker run` command they should be after image name. You are placing the before. There should be a separate method to pass application arguments, something like Cmd() or Args().